# How does the solarian's Starquake zenith revelation work?

Tags: class-feature, movement, damage, starfinder

For the [Starquake](http://www.starjammersrd.com/classes/solarian/#Starquake_Su_Graviton_mode) zenith revelation, it states:

> As a move action, you can move up to your speed along the ground without provoking attacks of opportunity. Each creature you are adjacent to at any point during that movement takes 1d8 bludgeoning damage [...]

Does this mean that if they were to move 8 squares in a circle around one opponent, that enemy would take 8d8 bludgeoning damage?

Answer (score 3):

## No, he would only take 1d8

As noted the Starquake zenith revelation states (emphasis mine):

> As a move action, you can move up to your speed along the ground without provoking attacks of opportunity. Each creature you are adjacent to **at any point during that movement** takes 1d8 bludgeoning damage [...]

Here at any point means that each creature you are adjacent to at all gets the damage. If you would have done damage multiple times it would have said so in some form of "every time you are adjacent".

The big benefit from Starquake is offcourse the AoO free movement that can get you out of a tight spot or in a better position.

Comment: I thought that at first, but then I figured it was the whole "square rectangle" thing all over again.

Comment: wait does this mean there's only one shockwave at any one point during the movement? Seems kinda weak

Comment: Ok hang on then by that logic that means that if I encircle one guy and he has  guys surrounding him at a 10ft radius the guy in the middle gets hit 8 times and the other guys would get hit once each

Comment: The answers says literally the opposite of that.  Each of the 9 targets is damaged once.

Comment: And it's not weak because 1) It's an additional affect on top of regular movement in a Move Action, allowing you to continue the rest of your turn and 2) It prevents you from provoking AoO, the true benefit of the ability

Comment: @ninjahX what Ifusaso says. All of them are hit once. Plus you get AoO free movement.